# What are the possible ways to define parallel composition in Coq apart from using list?

Tags: coq

I know how to use the list to define it but expecting something other than this. Because I think it is not possible to prove associativity and commutative property if we define it using list.

Comment: Sorry, this question is missing context. What do you exactly mean by "parallel composition"?

Comment: Several processes running in parallel. For example P1 || P2 || ....|| Pn ---> P1' || P2' || .... || Pn. where multiple processes can take step in one step. So if we use list we can define it as list of processes. But the property like commutative can not be proved if we define it using list.

Comment: What is your definition of equality for processes? Note that it is common to provide commutativity in the definition of process congruence.

Comment: It is similar to the features of Pi calculus. Structural congruence

Comment: Then note that the equality induced by the concurrence does not correspond to Coq's equality ! In fact, under pi's congruence commutativity is an _axiom_. So in Coq you cannot "prove" it. What you can do is to work _modulo_ the congruence. For that, you have several approaches, the first one is to use `Setoids`, the second one is more advanced and involves decidadable congruences, cf. "Cyril Cohen:
Pragmatic Quotient Types in Coq. ITP 2013"

Comment: To express it in a different way, in Coq equality is "syntactical". Thus, the process `P || Q` is certainly not syntactically equal to `Q || P` and it will never be. Now, you can use your custom equality relation (my first solution up), or if you can compute a canonical form for every process, then you can work with canonical forms which will indeed be syntactically equal.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But my main question was is there any way to represent parallel compositions of processes other than list of processes.

Comment: My second suggestion indeed provides an alternative representation. You can use an inductive with a `par` constructor, but that won't solve your stated problem. [I am not sure you understand it]

Comment: I defined it like this:

Comment: And then I proved theorems like this:

Comment: Said in a different way, you could represent your processes even using an encoding to N or whatever exotic device you would like, however unless you can compute a canonical form for processes, such representations are not going to be provably equal under commutativity. So either that, or either you build your own notion of equality, in Coqspeak "a setoid". Maybe it is a good moment to actually discuss some code.

Comment: I was just curious to know that my notations and thinking of the way to define is correct or not as I am a new user of coq.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look to https://github.com/coq-contribs/pi-calc , it is reasonably straightforward. Your `parallel_commutative`theorem is actually weird, in fact you are not proving any notion of similarity between the two processes, but your theorem says "given a process `P||Q` I can build a process `Q || P`, which of course is quite straighforward.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing that you are asking about parallel composition of state machines.  There are many ways to model them in Coq's logic, I don't know if lists are the best way...

If you define the steps as propositional relations you can compose two machines "in parallel" by creating a new inductive relation that can take a step either in one of the machines, or in the other.

This is sketch is not the most general way to write it, but hopefully it gets the idea across.

Suppose the machines can take steps between the states A, B, or C.  Machine M1 behaves in one way, and M2 in another. I.e. M1 can step from A to B *or* C, from B to C, and from C to A.  M2 can only step from A to C, and from C to A.

```
Inductive state : Set := A | B | C.

Inductive M1 : state -> state -> Prop :=
  s1 : M1 A B | s2 : M1 A C | s3 : M1 B C | s4 : M1 C A.

Inductive M2 : state -> state -> Prop := 
   ss1 : M2 A C | ss2 : M2 C A.
```

The we can create a new step relation for the combined system

```
Inductive M1M2 : (state*state) -> (state*state) -> Prop :=
| st1 s1 s1' s2: M1 s1 s1' ->  M1M2 (s1, s2) (s1', s2)  (* M1 takes a step *)
| st2 s1 s2 s2': M2 s2 s2' ->  M1M2 (s1, s2) (s1, s2'). (* M2 takes a step *)
```